# IPv6 Regular Expression (RegEx) Not Working in PL/SQL

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, ipv6

I can't seem to find out why this regular expression is not working in `PL/SQL`.

```
if ( REGEXP_LIKE(v,'/^(?>(?>([a-f0-9]{1,4})(?>:(?1)){7}|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9](?>:|$)){8,})((?1)(?>:(?1)){0,6})?::(?2)?)|(?>(?>(?1)(?>:(?1)){5}:|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){6,})(?3)?::(?>((?1)(?>:(?1)){0,4}):)?)?(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])(?>\.(?4)){3}))$/iD') ) then
```

It's for validating IPv4 and IPv6, it came from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1934546/3112803

Not sure if this has anything to do with it but I also asked this question about the `D` flag on the end: [What Does This Regular Expression (RegEx) Flag Mean /iD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940348/what-does-this-regular-expression-regex-flag-mean-id)

For some reason this regular expression works for ***most*** of my tests on this site: http://regex101.com/ but in `PL/SQL` everything is invalid.

What I mean by ***most*** is that there are some cases where I find it fails, but I've been searching for days and this is the best one I could find that is under 512 characters (512 is the limit when using `REGEXP_LIKE` in `PL/SQL`)

I'd appreciate any help.  Thanks!

These are the test cases I'm using...

```
{1: Initial address, regex should say valid/match}
select isValid('2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8329','ipv6') from dual;

{2: After removing all leading zeroes, regex should say valid/match}
select isValid('2001:db8:0:0:0:ff00:42:8329','ipv6') from dual;

{3: After omitting consecutive sections of zeroes, regex should say valid/match}
select isValid('2001:db8::ff00:42:8329','ipv6') from dual;

{4: The loopback address, regex should say valid/match}
select isValid('0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001','ipv6') from dual;

{5: The loopback address be abbreviated to ::1 by using both rules, regex should say valid/match}
select isValid('::1','ipv6') from dual;

{6: This should be valid/match}
select isValid('ABCD:ABCD:ABCD:ABCD:ABCD:ABCD:192.168.158.190','ipv6') from dual;

{7: This should be valid/match}
select isValid('::','ipv6') from dual;

{8: IPv6 applications to communicate directly with IPv4 applications, regex should say valid/match}
select isValid('0:0:0:0:0:ffff:192.1.56.10','ipv6') from dual;

{9: should NOT be valid/match}
select isValid('::ffff:192.1.56.10/96','ipv6') from dual;

{old formats used for tunneling, these should NOT be valid/matches}
{10}
select isValid('0:0:0:0:0:0:192.1.56.10','ipv6') from dual;
{11}
select isValid('::192.1.56.10/96','ipv6') from dual;

{These 4 should be valid/match}
{12}
select isValid('::FFFF:129.144.52.38','ipv6') from dual;
{13}
select isValid('::129.144.52.38','ipv6') from dual;
{14}
select isValid('::FFFF:d','ipv6') from dual;
{15}
select isValid('1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A','ipv6') from dual;

{These 4 should NOT be valid/match}
{16}
select isValid('::FFFF:d.d.d','ipv6') from dual;
{17}
select isValid('::FFFF:d.d','ipv6') from dual;
{18}
select isValid('::d.d.d','ipv6') from dual;
{19}
select isValid('::d.d','ipv6') from dual;
```

I was told test #6 was wrong, `ABCD:ABCD:ABCD:ABCD:ABCD:ABCD:192.168.158.190` is not a valid IPv6 address, is that correct?

Test cases 8-11 came from here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzai2%2Frzai2ipv6addrformat.htm but I was told 10&11 are no longer used.

Comment: Unfortunately, Oracle supports only narrow part of RegExp language.  You regexp would not work in Oracle.

Comment: For the second time, test case 6 is not valid. 10 and 11 are not either.

Comment: Yes, I am aware.  It was mentioned below as well.  I'll update the question so there is no confusion.  This accepted answer is the best I've found so far.  @nhahtdh however disagrees with you about the format of item #6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of doing everything in a single regex, it is better to break the regex into smaller ones and test them:

```
if (
    /* IPv6 expanded */
    REGEX_LIKE(v, '\A[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7}\z', 'i')
    /* IPv6 shorthand */
    OR (NOT REGEX_LIKE(v, '\A(.*?[a-f0-9](:|\z)){8}', 'i')
        AND REGEX_LIKE(v, '\A([a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,6})?::([a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,6})?\z', 'i'))
    /* IPv6 dotted-quad notation, expanded */
    OR REGEX_LIKE(v, '\A[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}\z', 'i')
    /* IPv6 dotted-quad notation, shorthand */
    OR (NOT REGEX_LIKE(v, '\A(.*?[a-f0-9]:){6}', 'i')
        AND REGEX_LIKE(v, '\A([a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,4})?::([a-f0-9]{1,4}:){0,5}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}\z', 'i'))
   ) then
```

This only tests for IPv6. IPv4 is not allowed.

Since PL/SQL flavor doesn't have subroutine calls `(?n)`, there is no choice but to expand everything out. And the lack of negative look-ahead `(?!pattern)` forces us to simulate it with 2 regex testing operations.

`\A` and `\z` are used for matching beginning and the end of the string, since both of them are not affected by flags, and `\z` behavior is the same as `$` under `D` mode in PCRE.

Comment: nicely done!
note: [a-f0-9] could be replaced by [[:xdigit:]] what could be more readable if you go crazy by all the digits (and you could leave out the i switch)

Comment: This is great! This is the closest answer so far and I've been searching for a long time.  I added my test cases to the original question.  Your pattern says number 6 is a match, but I was told that's not a valid IPv6 address?  It also fails on tests 9 & 11.  But I'm not sure if those are valid formats anymore.  I have another post very similar to this one for the same thing but for ColdFusion also (in case you want points there as well): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631669/regular-expression-regex-for-ipv6-separate-from-ipv4  Thank you!

Comment: @gfrobenius: I am not sure why 6 is not a valid IPv6. Format-wise, it should not be wrong. Test 9 and 11 are for IPv6 address **prefix**, not an IPv6 address.

Comment: Thank you for **not** using [[:xdigit:]] - not supported in javascript (and had to swap `\A` for `^` and `\z` for `$`), but works perfectly!

Comment: @cale_b: `[[:xdigit:]]` is simply `[A-Fa-f0-9]`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to get rid of the / at the start and the /iD from the end this is part of the perl syntax indicating it is a regex.

the i switch at the end means ignore case and can be given as an extra argument of your regexp_like, so:

```
if ( REGEXP_LIKE(v,'^(?>(?>([a-f0-9]{1,4})(?>:(?1)){7}|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9](?>:|$)){8,})((?1)(?>:(?1)){0,6})?::(?2)?)|(?>(?>(?1)(?>:(?1)){5}:|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){6,})(?3)?::(?>((?1)(?>:(?1)){0,4}):)?)?(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])(?>\.(?4)){3}))$','i') ) the
```

There are more issues, as perl regular expressions are not 100% equivalent to oracle regular expressions, and I see patter used here that are not available like ?>
Maybe you can split up the regexp between ipv4 and ipv6 to avoid hitting the limit in oracle. And just do REGEXP_LIKE(ip,'ipv4pattern') or REGEXP_LIKE(ip,'ipv6pattern')

Adjusting the ipv4 part of the above regex to something that works in oracle gives me:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(ip,'^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])$','i')
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, I forgot that flags needed to be separated by a comma in the `REGEXP_LIKE()` call.  Unfortunately it still didn't help.  All tests come back as invalid.  I think @EgorSkriptunoff might be right.

Comment: I edited my post to include a working regex in oracle for the ipv4 part.

Comment: Yes, I already have a separate IPv4 working, but thanks, I'll compare yours to mine.  And yes, I do want them separate.  But I have been trying to find a **IPv6 only** solution for a couple weeks and still can't find one.  Here was my initial attempt to find one: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631669/regular-expression-regex-for-ipv6-separate-from-ipv4**.  And here are my latest test cases: **http://regex101.com/r/sV5cZ3**.  I still haven't found a IPv6 only RegEx that works in `PL/SQL` that works for those test cases.

Comment: I found this post that provides functions for converting ipv6 strings, maybe you can use them and test if it returns NULL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470244/oracle-pl-sql-versions-of-inet6-aton-and-ntoa-functions

Answer (score 1):

```
REGEXP_LIKE(ip,'^(([\dA-F]{1,4}:([\dA-F]{1,4}:([\dA-F]{1,4}:([\dA-F]{1,4}:([\dA-F]{1,4}:[\dA-F]{0,4}|:[\dA-F]{1,4})?|(:[\dA-F]{1,4}){0,2})|(:[\dA-F]{1,4}){0,3})|(:[\dA-F]{1,4}){0,4})|:(:[\dA-F]{1,4}){0,5})((:[\dA-F]{1,4}){2}|:(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9])?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9])?\d)){3})|(([\dA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}|:):[\dA-F]{0,4}|([\dA-F]{1,4}:){7}:)\z', 'i')
```

Modified from the XML regex at http://home.deds.nl/~aeron/regex/